# My PopUp Feature from OpenLayers doesn't work well when I add points on the map. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, openlayers

I'm using [PopUp Feature](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html) from OpenLayers to show some info in a map when someone clicks on different points (points stored in a **vector source**) and I get a weird behavior from my popup:

[image: Weird behavior]

This is how I'm using the popup:

- first: I have a vector source that stores some points from an API when **ngOnInit()** function is called;
- on the **ngOnInit()** function I have a function named **buildMap()** where I build the map for the angular component I'm using and where I call the function **setupFeaturePopup(map)** which initialize the popup like this:

  ```
  private setupFeaturePopup(map: Map) {
   this.popup = new PopupFeature({
     popupClass: 'default anim',
     select: this.select,
     canFix: true,
     onshow: params => {
       const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-popupfeature');
       if (elements.length > 0) {
         const a = document.createElement('a');
         const linkText = document.createTextNode('Details');
         const n = document.getElementById('monitoring-icon');
         if (n) {
           a.appendChild(n.cloneNode(true));
         }
         a.title = 'Details';
         a.style.bottom = '0';
         a.style.padding = '0.27em';
         a.style.position = 'absolute';
         a.style.marginLeft = '10px';
         a.onclick = () => {
           this.openDeviceMonitoring();
         };
         elements.item(0)?.appendChild(a);
       }
     },
     template: function (feature) {
       if (feature.get('issi')) {
         return {
           title: 'name',
           attributes: {
             issi: {title: 'ISI'},
             status: {title: 'Status'},
             lat: {title: 'Lat'},
             lon: {title: 'Lon'},
             location_date: {title: 'Date'},
           }
         };
       } else {
         return {
           title: 'name',
           attributes: {
             issi: {title: 'ISI', visible: false},
             status: {title: 'Status', visible: false},
             lat: {title: 'Lat'},
             lon: {title: 'Lon'},
             location_date: {title: 'Date'},
           }
         };
       }
     },
   });
   map.addOverlay(this.popup);}
  ```

The PopUps from the first vector source work fine:

[image: Working popup]

My problem occurs when I want to bring other points (**stored on another vector source**) on the map from an API when someone push a button (long after **ngOnInit()** function is called).

Mentions:

**I see the new points on the map, the problem is when I click them*

***All this is happening in the same angular component*

What am I doing wrong?